# how ever I disabled autosave draft but still it works

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am writing a wordpress function to trigger a function after a post is published I am using the *add_action("save_post", "")* but I just want my function to be trigger only when the user clicks the publish button nothing else

Here is what I wrote

```
add_action("save_post", "test");

    function test( $post_id ) {
    if( !(wp_is_post_revision( $post_id ) ) || wp_is_post_autosave( $post_id ) ) {
        return;
    }
        $post_log = get_stylesheet_directory() . "/post.txt";
        $message =  get_the_title($post_id) . ' was saved';

        if( file_exists ( $post_log )) {
            $file = fopen( $post_log, 'a');
            fwrite($file, $message."\n");
        } else {
            $file = fopen( $post_log, "w");
            fwrite($file, $message."\n");
        }
        fclose($file);

}
```

but by this code the results that are saved twice for every post in my *post.txt* file one for autosave draft one for regular save.

Comment: Where are you running this? Directly in a browser? In Node.js? In a browser but with something like Webpack converting it? Somewhere else?

Comment: So "Directly in a browser".

Comment: however when I am trying the same file in html format opened with parcel localhost it works fine, but in any other server it does not work

Comment: What version of GSAP are you using? Most likely the [GSAP installation page](https://greensock.com/install) and videos therein can help you get GSAP imported correctly, especially the install helper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Browsers are not Node.js. Websites are loaded over HTTP, not from a filesystem. Browsers do not have Node.js's module name resolution system. You can't just put the module name there.

Replace `'gsap'` with the URL to the module.

e.g. `from '/path/to/gsap.js';`.

> however when I am trying the same file in html format opened with parcel localhost it works fine, but in any other server it does not work

Well, yes. That's the **point** of parcel: To bundle JavaScript modules to run in a browser.

You seem to be successfully using the development server to build the project, but you're just copying the development files to your production webserver instead of [making a production build](https://parceljs.org/production.html) and copying the output of that.

Comment: @MohsenAmani — No. Nothing I said has anything to do with the organisation of the files in your file system.